# Docker Security: Whether just blocking port is sufficient?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a little problem. I've tried to secure my MongoDB in docker container (btw I'm using docker-compose) by restricting access from outside of the docker network. I've just simply removed ports from docker-compose mongo services and it worked, I could not access it from outside. But is that enough? And is it the right decision? Maybe someone has another solution.

Comment: You really have not said what you have done to secure it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few best practices you can follow from the security point of view:

1. **Prefer Minimal Base Image:** The base image you select can also have vulnerabilities, you can look for security vulnerabilities before selecting the base image. Select the minimal base image as it may ensure that there are fewer vulnerabilities.
2. **Least Privileged User:** If no user is specified in the Dockerfile, by default the container is run using root privilege. To restrict access, create a dedicated user and user group in the docker image.
3. **Sign and Verify the images:** We run the docker images in our production environment, thus it is quite important to authenticate the docker image before using it. You should sign your docker image and before running you should also verify it.
4. **Use Security Softwares and linters:** Use security software to scan your docker images for any vulnerabilities, you can also use a linter which statically analyzes your Dockerfile and gives a warning when there is a security vulnerability.
5. **Don’t leak sensitive information to Docker images:** The secrets must be kept outside of the Dockerfile. If you copy the secret, then they get cached on the intermediate docker container, to avoid this problem, you can use multi-stage build or docker secret commands.

**Credits:** Thanks to Liran Tal and Omer Levi Hevroni for the [blog](https://snyk.io/blog/10-docker-image-security-best-practices/). I learned these best practices from their blog, please visit this blog for more details and a few more best practices.